# Outputting double pointer member of an object with overloaded stream insertion operator?

Tags: c++, arrays, oop, matrix, double-pointer

I am currently implementing a class that can represent matrices using dynamic arrays with double pointers (of type double), overloaded `*/-/+ operators` for **matrix arithmetic** & **overloaded stream insertion operator** for outputting the matrices.

My project requires that the user inputs a sequence of inputs separated by spaces into a string, with the number of terms in the string equating the number of columns, and the number of string inputs equating rows. I've been able to successfully write out my class function definitions, but when I compile and run my code, once the program reaches the overloaded insertion operator call, it only prints one memory address rather than each value in the array regardless of how many rows or columns I try.

My class definition:

```
class clMatrix {
  private:
    int rows, cols ;
    double **arr ;
  public:
    clMatrix() ;
    ~clMatrix() ;
    void userInput(char matrixId, int &rowN, int &colN) ;
    friend ostream &operator<<(ostream& os, const clMatrix*&) ;
    friend clMatrix &operator+(const clMatrix&, const clMatrix&) ;
    friend clMatrix &operator-(const clMatrix&, const clMatrix&) ;
    friend clMatrix &operator*(const clMatrix&, const clMatrix&) ;
} ;
```

My class function definitions(specifically input and output, as the arithmetic operators I haven't even tested since I lack output to test) and main:

Output function:

```
ostream& operator<<(ostream& os, const clMatrix *&printMatrix) {
  for(int i = 0; i < printMatrix->rows; ++i) {
    os << "\nRow " << i+1 << ": " ;
    for(int j = 0; j < printMatrix->cols; ++j) {
      os << printMatrix->arr[i][j] << " " ;
    }
  }
  os << endl ;
  return os ;
}
```

Input function:

```
void clMatrix::userInput(char matrixId, int &rowN, int &colN) {
  string in ;
  int idx, rowLen, colLen ;
  double rowarr[50] ;
  bool firstRow = 1 ;
  colLen = 0 ;
  rowLen = 0 ;
  idx = 0 ;
  cout << "Matrix: " << "'" << matrixId << "'" << endl ;
  cout << "Enter row 1: " ;
  getline(cin,in) ;
  while(in != "") {
    ++rowLen ;
    stringstream iss(initial) ;
    while(iss >> rowarr[idx]) {
      ++idx ;
    }
    if(firstRow) {
      colLen = idx ;
      firstRow = 0 ;
    }
    cout << "Enter row " << rowLen + 1 << ": " ;
    getline(cin,in) ;
  }
  idx = 0 ;
  rows = rowLen ;
  cols = colLen ;

  arr  = new double*[rows] ;
  for(int i = 0; i < rows; ++i) {
    arr[i] = new double[cols] ;
  }
  idx = 0 ;
  for(int i = 0; i < rows; ++i) {
    for(int j = 0; j < cols; ++j) {
      arr[i][j] = rowarr[idx] ;
      ++idx ;
    }
  }
}
```

Main function:

```
#ifndef HEADER_H
#define HEADER_H
#include "header.h"
int main() {
  clMatrix *aMatrix ;
  clMatrix *bMatrix ;
  aMatrix = new clMatrix ;
  bMatrix = new clMatrix ;
  char matrixId ;
  int rowsA, rowsB, colsA, colsB ;

  matrixId = 'A' ;
  cout << "Matrix A input:\n" ;
  aMatrix->userInput(matrixId,rowsA,colsA) ;

  matrixId = 'B' ;
  cout << "Matrix B input:\n" ;
  bMatrix->userInput(matrixId,rowsB,colsB) ;

  cout << "Matrix A output:\n" ;
  cout << aMatrix ;
  cout << "Matrix B output:\n" ;
  cout << bMatrix ;

  delete aMatrix ;
  delete bMatrix ;
  return 0 ;
}
```

When I run the program I get one, single heap-allocated address for each matrix and they are off by 32 bits I think? (My most recent run: 0x1dbcc20 and 0x1dbcc40). Would this mean that only my two integer member variables are being allocated for 16 bits each? If that's the case, is my memory allocation improper? I've also tried just about every possible gradation of dereferencing the double-type double pointer, but to no avail. Also, strangely the line:

```
os << "\nRow " << i+1 << ": " ;
```

from my stream insertion overload function never prints to console, despite it being intended to print for each row, yet the program skips it goes into the interior for loop and prints that one frickin' address. I simply don't understand.

I've run out of options (have been editing/recompiling/running and debugging in `GDB/valgrind` for the last 5 hours), exhausted just about every resource I could find relevant to my problem, and so now at 2:45 AM, terribly sleep deprived I turn to you, the brave souls of SO. Any help is greatly appreciated, thank you! (So sorry if this is incoherent and hard to understand I'm very tired!)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your stream-out operator has second formal parameter `const clMatrix *&printMatrix`. This is an lvalue reference to a const pointer to `clMatrix`. You're calling it with an lvalue non-const pointer to `clMatrix`, which will not bind to the reference (if it did, you could use it to violate const safety).

As a result, the only available overload is the `ostream` member function `operator<<(const void* value)`, which prints a raw pointer value.

Either of the following signatures will work:

```
operator<<(ostream&, const clMatrix*const &)
operator<<(ostream&, const clMatrix*)
```

But it would be more idiomatic to take the `clMatrix` parameter directly by const reference:

```
operator<<(ostream&, const clMatrix&)
```

Comment: Passing a non-referenced pointer parameter worked! I was under the impression from the way that my professor lectured about this that I had to pass const pointers by reference, but this makes a lot more sense. Seems redundant now unless I was actually trying to modify the pointer. Thank you very much!! Also, now I realize what people mean by idiomatic, the first set of parameters reads very much like "object pointer const reference".

Answer (score 0):

Is your overloaded operator called? `const clMatrix*&` seems freaky. Because of this, compiler chooses built-in `operator<<`. Pass simply const-reference to `clMatrix`. And call it `cout << *aMatrix`. If you do so, compiler won't mix up your overload with build-it `operator<<`.

Your code looks correct but quite complicated. I would use single `std::vector` or `std::valarray` to store all M*N values and refer to element using `arr[n*cols+m]`. Let user simply specify number of rows and columns beforehand, allocate enough memory and fill it with `std::cout >> arr[i*cols+j]`. Overload `operator>>` for input stream and your matrix instead of `userInput` function.

Comment: This worked as well, thank you! I think calling the insertion operator with 'cout << *clMatrix' was the key to passing by const reference which I had been missing. Oh and trust me, I know there are much more painless ways to do this, but my teacher wants us to bleed a little to develop our understanding/feel and we haven't covered templates yet so I haven't ventured into vectors as of yet.